# Need XML from parent and child table from Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

In a project on which i am working on, we need to create an XML and pass it on to an interface and i am facing issues while creating an XML containing data from parent table and its subsequent child table.

parent table :- Department should be like

```
dept_id     dept_name
1           History
2           Biology
```

CHild table :- employee should be like

```
emp_id      emp_name     dept_id
1           Helen         1
2           Martha        1 
3           John          1
4           Carol         2
```

So the resulting XML should be like for department id=1

```
`<department>
<dept_id>1</dept_id>
<dept_name>History</dept_name>
</department>
<employee>
<emp_id>1</emp_id>
<emp_name>Helen</emp_name>
</employee>
<employee>
<emp_id>2</emp_id>
<emp_name>Martha</emp_name>
</employee>
<employee>
<emp_id>3</emp_id>
<emp_name>John</emp_name>
</employee>'
```

If anyone knows a better way of doing this then it would be of great help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: A better way than what? What are you doing now, and what issues do you have? You also have an XML fragment, not a valid document - there is no root node. Are you sure that's the format you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (with the employee nodes in the department node so it is not a fragment):

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT(
         "department",
         XMLFOREST(
           e.dept_id AS "dept_id",
           d.dept_name AS "dept_name"
         ),
         XMLAGG(
           XMLELEMENT(
             "employee",
             XMLFOREST(
               emp_id AS "emp_id",
               emp_name AS "emp_name"
             )
           )
         )
       )
FROM   employees e
       INNER JOIN departments d
       on ( e.dept_id = d.dept_id )
WHERE  e.dept_id = 1
GROUP BY e.dept_id, d.dept_name;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...
I was looking for this kind of query only.

Comment: @user1654571 If this or any other answer has answered your question you can mark it as accepted (tick the green check mark below the voting buttons to the left of the answer) - this will let other users know your issue is resolved.

Comment: Thanks again...
Done and thanks for helping a newb :)